# Using PasswordValidator in a Roo-generated jsp page

Tags: dojo, spring-roo, spring-js

When scaffolding the first controller, Spring Roo will generate a bunch of tags and one of them is WEB-INF/tags/form/fields/input.tagx

This is a nice tag, it allows me to specify the error messages, regex expression for the field validation, etc. It uses spring-js dojo integration to do client-side validation. It decorates an existing input in the following fashion:

```
<script type="text/javascript">
        Spring.addDecoration(new Spring.ElementDecoration({elementId : '_${sec_field}_id', widgetType : 'dijit.form.ValidationTextBox', widgetAttrs : {promptMessage: '${sec_field_validation}', invalidMessage: '${sec_field_invalid}', required : ${required}, ${sec_validation_regex} missingMessage : '${sec_field_required}' }})); 
</script>
```

What I would like to do is to create another tag like this, let's call it passwords.tagx, which will decorate 2/3 existing input fields and provide the old (optional) / new / verify password functionality.

There is a dojo widget for this, `dojox.form.PasswordValidator`, which seems to be using the `ValidationTextBox` from previous snippet.

The question is, how to integrate these two tags, so I can use PasswordValidator, but still provide regex, error messages,  and other stuff that I can normally use with ValidationTextBox.

Any help is greatly appreciated.

Comment: did you get through this yet?

Answer (score 0):

Although `passwordValidator` is using `validationTextBox` for these input box, but it does not pass these attributes down, check

```
_createSubWidgets: function(){
....

  widgets[idx] = new c(p, i);

}
```

I think you can pass down what ever attributes for the `validationTextBox` as you wish, currently seems only required attribute is passed.